# Is log4j compatible with jdk21?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, log4j2, uberjar

When I try to build with ant single jar file which uses `jar-in-jar-loader` everything inside looks as expected. The manifest content is

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.10.14
Created-By: 21+35-LTS-2513 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
Rsrc-Main-Class: a.b.MyApp
Multi-Release: true
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ lib/log4j/log4j-api-2.22.1.jar lib/log4j/log4j-cor
 e-2.22.1.jar lib/jdatepicker-1.3.4.jar
Class-Path: .
```

`jar-in-jar-loader.zip` is generated by eclipse 2023-12 which uses jdk21, all files seems to be in place in myApp.jar
However when I use `java -jar myApp.jar` I see

```
WARNING: Runtime environment or build system does not support multi-release JARs. This will impact location-based features.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:62)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No class provided, and an appropriate one cannot be found.
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.callerClass(LogManager.java:585)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:610)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:597)
        at a.b.log.Log.getLogger(Log.java:48)
        at a.b.MyApp.handleInputParameters(MyApp.java:97)
        at a.b.MyApp.main(MyApp.java:33)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        ... 2 more
```

When I run the app under eclipse everything works properly.
Is that means log4j can't be used with jdk21 (I use Oracle version)?
How to check it? I tried on log4j web page and I found nothing (especially in changelog). I also tried to downgrade project to jdk17, also nothing.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: I vote to reopen because (1) this error message is different to the proposed duplicate, and (2) the answers in the "duplicate" are not relevant to this question.

Comment: What I find puzzling is the warning "Runtime environment or build system does not support multi-release JARs." (which is in fact the root cause of your problem) but your settings show that multi-release is true.

Comment: *However when I use java -jar myApp.java I see...* That doesn't make sense. Why not something more like `java -jar myApp.jar`?

Comment: Oh, sorry. This is mistake. Corrected.

Comment: I just also tried log4j v 2.22.0 and 3.0 beta. No difference.
@k314159 Indeed I also noticed this fact. And all solutions I found indicated this is only activity I should do: just add multi-release. Maybe this is ignored from some version of java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually caused by a bug in the Eclipse `jar-in-jar` loader: cf. [eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui#1057](https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui/issues/1057).

In the meantime you can:

- either force all JAR files to be opened in multi-release mode by setting `-Djdk.util.jar.enableMultiRelease=force`,
- switch to another loader. [`spring-boot-loader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html) is much better maintained, available on Maven Central and it does not create temporary files to open embedded libraries.

**Edit**: the `3.0.0` betas are **not** multi-release JARs, so they should not be affected by the problem. If they are, please [submit a bug report](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/issues).

Comment: Do you mean I should use command this way `java -Djdk.util.jar.EnableMultiRelease=force -jar myapp.jar`?

Comment: @rainbox: Sorry, I had a small typo in the answer it should be `java -Djdk.util.jar.enableMultiRelease=false -jar myapp.jar` with a small `e`. The property is documented in [`JarFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/jar/JarFile.html).

Comment: Your comment says `false` but your answer says `force`. Could you please clarify which one it is, for the sake of possible future readers.

Comment: @k314159: sorry, I meant `force`.

Comment: Using jog4j 3.0.0 solves the problem. `Multi-Release: true` is no longer necessary in MANIFEST file.